# Subconsultas con múltiples registros en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

tengo un problema a la hora de hacer una consulta dependiente de una subconsulta.
Tengo el siguiente código.

```
SELECT c.cliente FROM cartera AS a
        INNER JOIN cliente_operaciones AS b
            ON a.nro_cuenta = b.nro_cuenta and b.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
        INNER JOIN cliente_datos AS c
            ON b.cliente = c.cliente and c.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
```

Esta consulta me devuelve 35 registros con un numero entero cada uno. Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora me gustaría obtener otros datos a partir de esos 35 registros obtenidos.

Estoy metiendo todo esto como una subconsulta de esta manera.

```
SELECT *  FROM ahorro AS cah
    INNER JOIN cliente_operaciones AS b
        ON cah.nro_cuenta = b.nro_cuenta and b.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
    INNER JOIN cliente_datos AS c
        ON  c.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050' and c.cliente = b.cliente and c.cliente =
           (SELECT c.cliente FROM cartera AS a --Empieza la subconsulta
            INNER JOIN cliente_operaciones AS b
                ON a.nro_cuenta = b.nro_cuenta and b.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
            INNER JOIN cliente_datos AS c
                ON b.cliente = c.cliente and c.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050') -- Termina la subconsulta
WHERE cah.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050' and  cah.estado = 1
ORDER BY cah.nro_cuenta
```

Pero al ejecutar me devuelve este error

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto
> cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza
> como expresión.

Limitando la subconsulta a solo un registro (SELECT TOP 1), se ejecuta correctamente, ahora como lo hago con todos los registros.
Espero que me puedan ayudar. :)

Comment: Prueba cambiando el último = en la línea 5 por IN, algo así: `c.cliente IN (SELECT...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata a la subconsulta como si fuera otra tabla:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ahorro AS cah
    INNER JOIN cliente_operaciones AS b
      ON cah.nro_cuenta = b.nro_cuenta and b.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
    INNER JOIN cliente_datos AS c
      ON c.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050' 
        and c.cliente = b.cliente 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT c.cliente 
                   FROM cartera AS a --Empieza la subconsulta
                     INNER JOIN cliente_operaciones AS b
                       ON a.nro_cuenta = b.nro_cuenta and b.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
                     INNER JOIN cliente_datos AS c
                       ON b.cliente = c.cliente and c.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'
               ) sub -- Termina la subconsulta
      ON sub.cliente = c.cliente
  WHERE cah.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050' 
    and cah.estado = 1
  ORDER BY cah.nro_cuenta
```

Manejar la subconsulta en un `IN` es ineficiente.

Comment: Gracias!! Aunque el tiempo de ejecución es un poco más que usando IN.

Comment: Probablemente cuestión de índices.